# How to detect URL in a textarea and validate it?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to detect (in a textarea) if any URL present in the text area value ? I will wish to detect urls throughout the entry, eg run a check on the word that has been typed after each space or if I am pasting anything in the textarea.

Also can I be able to check if it's valid URL. Because if it is valid than I will make an api call based on that valid url.

Thank you in advance.

```
<textarea (keyup)=onKeyUp($event) [(ngModel)]="textval" (paste)="onPaste($event)"></textarea>

onKeyUp(event){
  //check if any url present in value on key up
}


onPaste(event : any){
  ////check if any url present in value if pasting anything
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Router` to get the URL and map that to you ngModel variable textval and have a pattern validation if that is a valid input then you send it. This is how you use Router in your component and pattern validation

```
textval: any;

constructor(private currentRoute: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.textval = this.currentRoute.url;
}
```

RegExp to validate valid URL is (This is one example you may change it based on your requirement)

```
/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/;
```

Use this on textarea

```
<textarea [pattern]="/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/" (keyup)=onKeyUp($event) [(ngModel)]="textval" (paste)="onPaste($event)"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use reactive forms from angular, you can add a regular expression as a validator

```
const reg = '(https?://)?([\\da-z.-]+)\\.([a-z.]{2,6})[/\\w .-]*/?';

this.form = fb.group({

  url: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(reg)]]

})
```